# Comparison of stock market volatilities

Tags: probability, finance

I was trying to compare the volatilities of the stock market index of China and America. But I realized that a direct comparison of historical data would not be fair. The Chinese market has a rule that restricts changes in stock prices to be within $\pm$ 10% everyday. No such rule exists in the US.

I couldn't just eliminate days where the American market changed by more than 10%, because the next day the change would have been bigger if previous' day's change was restricted to be within 10%. So is there any fair way to modify the data for comparison?

Comment: The very definition of a volatility depends on a defined time interval. One might argue--I don't know how successfully--that government intervention cannot overcome market forces over the "longer" term. Thus, although *daily* volatilities are clearly affected, it is possible that weekly or monthly volatilities are much less strongly affected. Perhaps these thoughts will point you in a fruitful direction for further investigation...